# How can I add the Apache POI Library in Eclipse - for Selenium Webdriver project?

Tags: apache, selenium, webdriver, apache-poi

I need to add the apache poi to my project (I need hssf, ss and xssf). I downloaded a jar file from the internet but it does not contain xssf. I went to http://poi.apache.org/ and I downloaded this: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/release/src/poi-src-3.9-20121203.zip, I extract it..and got stucked. I tried Part 1 but that was only for JavaDoc.

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Did you try downloading the *binary* release (contains jars and dependencies) instead of the *source* release?

Comment: I tried your solution (which had the jars) and it worked. Thank you for being so prompt!

Answer (score 27):

1. Download [The latest stable release: Apache POI 3.16-FINAL](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.16-20170419.zip) distribution,
2. open your eclipse project properties,
3. Java Built Path > Libraries > Add external JARs,
4. then extract the zip file you downloaded and navigate the extracted folder,
5. select all the JARs under the sub folders (docs, lib, ooxml-lib),
6. then finally in the Order and Export section put marks to jar libs you just added,

and click OK.

Answer (score 18):

Promoting a comment to an answer

You should head to the [Apache POI Download Page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html), and then download the *binary* release. The binary releases have -bin- in their file names. The binary releases contain the POI jars, and [their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components).

What you've downloaded with -src- in the name is the source package, which contains everything you need to build Apache POI yourself, but if you just want to get started you're much better off with the pre-compiled binary package.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the Binary Artifacts of your suitable version where you will find all the necessary jars to add in your classpath to read/write data from Spreadsheets.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkDu7.png)