# Error For Below code

Tags: android

Getting Error for the below package:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
```

can any help me for the below code to resolve the error.

```
public class AndroidReadExcelActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            View writeButton = findViewById(R.id.write);
            writeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            View readButton = findViewById(R.id.read);
            readButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            View writeExcelButton = findViewById(R.id.writeExcel);
            writeExcelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            View readExcelButton = findViewById(R.id.readExcel);
            readExcelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.write:
                saveFile(this,"myFile.txt");
                break;
            case R.id.read:
                readFile(this,"myFile.txt");
                break;
            case R.id.writeExcel:
                saveExcelFile(this,"myExcel.xls");
                break;
            case R.id.readExcel:
                readExcelFile(this,"myExcel.xls");
                break;   
            }
        }

        private static boolean saveFile(Context context, String fileName) { 

            // check if available and not read only 
            if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only"); 
                return false; 
            } 

            // Create a path where we will place our List of objects on external storage 
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName); 
            PrintStream p = null; // declare a print stream object
            boolean success = false; 

            try { 
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file); 
                // Connect print stream to the output stream
                p = new PrintStream(os);
                p.println("This is a TEST");
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
                success = true; 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
            } finally { 
                try { 
                    if (null != p) 
                        p.close(); 
                } catch (Exception ex) { 
                } 
            } 

            return success; 
        } 

        private static void readFile(Context context, String filename) { 

            if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) 
            { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only"); 
                return; 
            } 

            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try
            { 
                File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename); 
                fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
                // Get the object of DataInputStream
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                //Read File Line By Line
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.w("FileUtils", "File data: " + strLine);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "File Data: " + strLine , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                in.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                Log.e("FileUtils", "failed to load file", ex); 
            } 
            finally { 
                try {if (null != fis) fis.close();} catch (IOException ex) {} 
            } 

            return;
        } 

        private static boolean saveExcelFile(Context context, String fileName) { 

            // check if available and not read only 
            if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only"); 
                return false; 
            } 

            boolean success = false; 

            //New Workbook
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

            Cell c = null;

            //Cell style for header row
            CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
            cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
            cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

            //New Sheet
            Sheet sheet1 = null;
            sheet1 = wb.createSheet("myOrder");

            // Generate column headings
            Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);

            c = row.createCell(0);
            c.setCellValue("Item Number");
            c.setCellStyle(cs);

            c = row.createCell(1);
            c.setCellValue("Quantity");
            c.setCellStyle(cs);

            c = row.createCell(2);
            c.setCellValue("Price");
            c.setCellStyle(cs);

            sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
            sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
            sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));

            // Create a path where we will place our List of objects on external storage 
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName); 
            FileOutputStream os = null; 

            try { 
                os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                wb.write(os);
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
                success = true; 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
            } finally { 
                try { 
                    if (null != os) 
                        os.close(); 
                } catch (Exception ex) { 
                } 
            } 

            return success; 
        } 

        private static void readExcelFile(Context context, String filename) { 

            if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) 
            { 
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only"); 
                return; 
            } 

            try{
                // Creating Input Stream 
                File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename); 
                FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

                // Create a POIFSFileSystem object 
                POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

                // Create a workbook using the File System 
                HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

                // Get the first sheet from workbook 
                HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

                /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
                Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

                while(rowIter.hasNext()){
                    HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                    while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                        HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                        Log.w("FileUtils", "Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }

            return;
        } 

        public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() { 
            String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) { 
                return true; 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 

        public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() { 
            String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) { 
                return true; 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: post the log cat error and may i know Did you added usermodel jar or package in your code?

Comment: Sorry sir its not at all executing the code...i have added the below jar files:jakarta-poi-2.5,poi-3.5-FINAL-sources and poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL and poi-ooxml-3.9.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: `help me for the below code to resolve the error` - **which** error?

Comment: I am not able the run the that code, so hw can i post the logcat..

Answer (score 0):

You need to Import **Apache POI library**

Tutorial using this library can be found [here](http://hmkcode.com/apache-poi-java-read-write-excel/)

Go through the official website for latest [library](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) release and go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958732/how-can-i-add-the-apache-poi-library-in-eclipse-for-selenium-webdriver-project) as well.

Jar Download [URL](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.10-FINAL-20140208.tar.gz) click on any mirror link under HTTP.

Comment: Hi Team,Can you give me the exact link to download the jar files, plz help me sir...

Answer (score 0):

public class AndroidReadExcelActivity

reemplaced for name your archive JAVA for example mainActivity

Comment: Try using the code tags to clearly tell the user what the answer is.